# Intra-JVM Profilers?

Tags: java, open-source, jvm, profiling

I've been reading up on [AppDynamics](http://www.appdynamics.com/) Lite all morning and absolutely love it! It's pretty nice to be able to drop a JAR into your web app (WAR), deploy it and have it automatically run perf tests on your app.

I was wondering if anything similar exist for full-fledged profiling? Something similar to, say, VisualVM, but that deploys as a JAR and that can be packaged inside a WAR?

Online searches didn't turn up much but then again I might not be searching for the right thing. I call this an "intra-JVM profiler" because its profiling the same Java process its running inside of (like AppDynamics).

I love open source but this is not a mandatory requisite. Thanks in advance for any pointers/recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

[Java Melody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) might be relevant for you.